# Matlab - Ignoring header text when using dlmread

Tags: matlab, file, file-io

I have many files with text:

```
LON   LAT   DEPTH  C
    9.0928    9.0928     91.       .22215180E+00
```

I using dlmread function:

```
data = dlmread(fname, ' ', 1, 0);
```

But I get error:

> Badly formed format string.

How can I ignore header text and get counts via dlmread in this case?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I works for me (R2015b).  But use `data = dlmread(fname, '', 1, 0)` to treat multiple spaces as a single delimiter

Answer (score 1):

The function `dlmread` is suited to read files with numeric data.

To read an input file with one or more header lines, you can use `importdata` as follows:

```
% Define the delimiter
delim=' ';
% Define the number of header lines
header_line=1;
% Read the inout file
C=importdata('in_.txt',delim,header_line)
```

The content of the input file is stored in the "C" `struct`; in particular, the "numeric data" are stored in the "data" field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also I find this option: textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f', 2, 'headerLines', 1);